# How can I save unicode columns in non-unicode Oracle database with VARCHAR2?

Tags: database, oracle, unicode, non-unicode

How can I save unicode characters in a Oracle database, configured in a non-unicode charset (this configurations is impossible to change)?

The text will be saved in VARCHAR2 columns (it can't be NVARCHAR2).

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways you can store arbitrary data (in this case UTF-encoded) in a `VARCHAR2` field:

- You could convert the Unicode characters to their [`U+XXXX` form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) or their `&#YYYY` form. Only some of the characters would need a conversion.
- You could store the binary data [`rawtohex`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions131.htm)-encoded.
- You could also use standard functions such as [`UTL_ENCODE.mimeheader_encode`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_encode.htm#i999461):

  ```
  /* needs to be checked on a non-unicode db */ 
  SQL> declare
    2     l nvarchar2(200);
    3     p nvarchar2(200);
    4  begin
    5     l := UTL_ENCODE.MIMEHEADER_ENCODE (
    6        buf            => nchr(352),--'Š',
    7        encode_charset => 'UTF8',
    8        encoding       => UTL_ENCODE.QUOTED_PRINTABLE
    9     );
   10     dbms_output.put_line('encoded string: ' || l);
   11     p := utl_encode.mimeheader_decode (
   12        buf => l
   13     );
   14     dbms_output.put_line('decoded string: ' || p);
   15  end;
   16  /

  encoded string: =?UTF8?Q?=C5=A0?=
  decoded string: Š

  Statement processed.
  ```

Comment: I don't think `utl_encode.mimeheader_encode` would work if the database character set didn't support the character you were trying to encode.  I would expect character set conversion to have converted the character to a replacement character that the database character set does support before the function could be called.

Comment: @JustinCave: does this function work with an NVARCHAR2 in a non-unicode database (I don't have access to such a db right now)?

Comment: I don't believe that there is an `NVARCHAR2` overload.  You could potentially pass in a character set with your `varchar2` but I'm not sure that would work from a client application-- I would expect character set conversion to convert the character set first.